# Как выбрать ячейки таблицы?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть таблица, и на некоторые ячейки, с помощью js я хочу присвоить display как none.
Но проблема в том, как отметить эти ячейки и как это сделать?

Comment: Нужно чтобы только определенные ячейки скрывались.

Нужно их чем то пометить (id, class или тому подобное) и, при вызове определенной функции, они скрывались.

Но как их пометить и перебрать?

Comment: Вы хотите скрыть сами ячейки или их содержимое? Или вы хотите скрыть столбец? Разница большая.

Comment: сами ячейки, причем их много

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> сами ячейки, причем их много

```
var tds = document.getElementById('mytable').getElementsByTagName('td');
tds[15].style.display = tds[24].style.display = tds[31].style.display = 'none';
```

Но я не беру на себя ответственность за развалившуюся таблицу.

Comment: На счет развалившейся таблицы не беспокойтесь, все продумано

Answer (score 0):

Jquery выдели нужные ячейки если знаешь какие тебе нужны и все.

А есть смысл делать display:none? нельзя их просто не выводить и не городить лишней работы себе? Если вопрос стоит только "не показать" ячейки.

Comment: нет, мне нужно чтобы они скрывались при нажатии на галочку.

Функция нужна.

Comment: Так наверное стоит и вопрос оформить подобающим образом, а то мы свои экстрасенсорные способности каждый раз не можем включать.

Answer (score 0):

Чистый JS:

Пробегитесь по всем рядам и строкам таблицы циклом. Занесите ссылки (document.element) на элементы в ячейки массива. Обращайтесь к ним на здоровье.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял у вас есть таблица в одном из столбцов есть чекбокс так ? если так то можно использовать parent()

например

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('checked'))
        $(this).parent('tr').hide();
    else
        return false;
});
```

Comment: Нет, есть отдельный чекбокс и на его нажатие, необходимые ячейки пропадают

Comment: какие это необходимые ??!?!  вы же их не с неба берете ... что в них находится, какой критерий?

Comment: Вот именно, вопрос в том, как пометить необходимые мне для скрытия ячейки.